# Font issue while writing text on image with PHP

Tags: php

My code is working when I call the font from my computer on localhost. As Example:
`$font = "C:\Windows\Fonts\arial.ttf";`

But it doesn't work when I put this arial font outside or upload the code on server.

My code is looking like this.

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg('main.jpg');
$black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$txt = "My name is Swapnil raja and I have created this image dynamically for featured image.";
$txtt = "Last Date";
$font = "arial.ttf"; //this font is available on the same place, where this code is

// THE IMAGE SIZE
$width = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

// THE TEXT SIZE
$text_size = imagettfbbox(24, 0, $font, $txt);
$text_width = max([$text_size[2], $text_size[4]]) - min([$text_size[0], $text_size[6]]);
$text_height = max([$text_size[5], $text_size[7]]) - min([$text_size[1], $text_size[3]]);

// CENTERING THE TEXT BLOCK

$centerX = CEIL(($width - $text_width) / 2);
$centerX = $centerX<0 ? 0 : $centerX;
$centerX = CEIL(($height - $text_height) / 2);
$centerY = $centerX<0 ? 0 : $centerX;


imagettftext($img, 24, 0, $centerX-200, $centerY, $black, $font, wordwrap($txt));
imagettftext($img, 24, 0, $centerX-120, $centerY-240, $white, $font, wordwrap($txtt));


// OUTPUT IMAGE
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagepng($img);
imagedestroy($png_image);
```

Thanks you in advance for the help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem using font with imagettftext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566236/problem-using-font-with-imagettftext)

Comment: I am not using GD library, so it should not be duplicate

Comment: can you please check any library to be enabled in server

Comment: @Justin It's not working even on localhost (wamp)

Comment: _“I am not using GD library”_ - yes, you are.

Comment: @misorude So you are here to find duplicate (Why don't you help people by giving answer ?) That duplicate post didn't help me to solve my problem